# How do i create polygons from a CSV file containing LSOA/post code data in QGIS?

Tags: csv, polygon, qgis, postal-code

I have a CSV file containing all of my city's post codes. this same file also contains lat/long coordinates, ward, ward code, district code, LSOA, etc.

How can I load this csv into qgis so that the post code areas or LSOA codes are presented as a shp/polygon layer? Thanks!

I tried loading in the CSV coordinates and joining the attributes with a second LSOA shape file (which does not contain the useful metadata of the CSV file).

I have also tried loading the CSV as a delimited text layer in a number of ways (specifying WKT geometry field, choosing no geometry field etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch a shapefile or geopackage with the loas in it and then join your csv file to it using the id codes that are present in each file. ONS have links for downloading the boundaries on their website.